# Adding p:socket causes "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it." during logout/login

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push

I have a datatable where users can modify rows. Everything was fine until I added Primefaces `<p:socket>`, so that if there are any changes, all the users working on the table are notified. But from time to time I see this xml error during login/logout on container managed authentication:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<partial-response id="j_id1"> 
<changes> 
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"> 
<![CDATA[ 8290402593671514094:3228216940573345142 ]]> 
</update> 
</changes> 
</partial-response>
```

All I did was to simply add code from [Primefaces notify showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml). Why does it show up?

Comment: I have researched all the questions on SO related to "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it", but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you using an authentication framework, if so which one and is it JSF ajax aware?

Comment: Yes, datatable uses ajax calls. And also yes, I am using authentication  provided by Java EE (security constraints, roles defined in web.xml), Wildfly as an application server. The error occurs when user logs out, or when logs in (supposed to see datatable but sees error), but not while working on datatable. Error is gone once page is refreshed

Comment: Container managed authentication is not JSF ajax aware. So, you're now saying that this doesn't happen during push notification, but only when user logs out or logs in?

Comment: no not during push notification, only during log in and log out, but this error occurred only after adding Notify feature, as shown in showcase (<p:socket.../> <script> ... </script>). If I get rid of it, everything works fine. Is inline javascript to blame?